# Hide mixed area in an AngularNVD3 charts

Tags: css, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

is there a a way to hide mixed area in an angular nvd3 charts?
in fact what I'm trying to do is to display only the difference between two area, I tried to put the first one with color white as the background color as it's always smaller then the second one, but it doesn't work, I checked also  the `mix-blend-mode` option but wasn't able to do that, any suggestion please?
here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WlCn5Q?p=preview) with an example

Comment: You want to hide the area which both areas have in common ? I don't think there is a built-in way to this as the opacity is set based on the number overlapping elements. But you could change the `fill-opacity` of the respective group element after creating the chart (`<g class=" nv-group nv-series-1"`). Nevertheless, why don't you calculate the difference at each point in time and show it as one line / area ?

Comment: @JohannesH is it possible to not start from 0?I mean just present the difference between both of them but not to start from 0? What I'm trying to do is to show the difference between the min and max